# php extract image from piped email

Tags: php, attachment, pipe

This is an extension to a question which I asked some time ago.

I am now interested in trying to get images out of an email piped to a php script. Where are they stored, or would they have to be decoded from the email?

I know there are imap functions but can they be used reading from stdin. I really no nothing, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm if i remember correctly the attach data from mail are saved at the bottom of itself base64 encoded, so retrieve data and use base64_decode to get the real value...
i'm not 100% sure anyway..

Comment: yea no that was the case. I just looked in the php manual and there was some talk of it not working so well for longer strings. I suppose I wondered whether there was an easier way/php function/class etc.